# Ember.js 'faker' is not defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I'm trying to start a server from a repo but having issues getting it started because of the following error:

```
ember serve


Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/

mirage/factories/page.js: line 4, col 42, 'faker' is not defined.

1 error

mirage/scenarios/default.js: line 7, col 19, 'domain' is defined but never used.
mirage/scenarios/default.js: line 13, col 105, Missing semicolon.
mirage/scenarios/default.js: line 5, col 7, 'ads' is defined but never used.

3 errors

===== 2 JSHint Errors
```

page.js:

```
import { Factory } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Factory.extend({
    permalink: function() { return '/' + faker.lorem.words(1); }
});
```

What is wrong here? I also manually installed faker using npm but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all and I'm still stuck with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`faker` should be included in the `ember-cli-mirage` namespace, so just import it along with `Factory`:

`import { Factory, faker } from 'ember-cli-mirage';`

Answer (score 0):

faker is not defined, so the code should have either one of these:

```
import { Factory } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

let faker = {
  lorem: {
    words: function() {}
  }
};
```

or

```
import { Factory } from 'ember-cli-mirage';
import faker from 'faker-module-in-the-repo-maybe';
```